# What Is The Most Accurate Way To Track The Position Of An iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, geolocation

**Situation:**
I am planning on making an iPhone app that would be played by users in a close vicinity needing to point their phones at the other users in the vicinity.
 The phone would have to know which other user the phone is being pointed at a specific time when a button is pressed.

**Question:**
What is the most accurate way to track the position of iPhones in your immediate distance? *(bluetooth, wifi, something else?)*
And how accurate of a radius can that be?
I am hoping for at most a 4 foot radius.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the location (latitude, longitude, or in reverse geo coding format) of the user by CLLocation in iOS and then there use this

```
user_distance = [firstLocation distanceFromLocation:secondLocation];
```

firstLocation and secondLocation are the objects of CLLocation.